# Regroup sublists by first element in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, grouping, sublist

I have a nested list that looks something like this:

```
first_list = [[a, 1], [b, 3], [a, 6], [a, 2], [b, 4], [b, 5], ...]
```

I want to group these by their first element, and create a new nested list that looks like:

```
new_list = [ [1, 6, 2, ...], [3, 4, 5, ...], ...]
```

where all of the elements that started with a go in the first sublist and so on. The number of different values a, b, etc. are not known before runtime, or I could do something like:

```
a_list = []
b_list = []
for tag, x in first_list:
    if tag == a:
        a_list.append(x)
    elif tag == b:
        b_list.append(x)
new_list = [a_list, b_list]
```

I am struggling to adapt this for an arbitrary number of tags, however.

I probably omitted an important part of the question, but I should say that I already have a list of "tags", i.e:

```
tags = [a, b, c, d, ...]
```

They are not actually characters, hence the lack of inverted commas, but they should be hashable in any case.

Comment: Variable number of names? Use a dictionary. `grouped = {}`, then in the loop `grouped.setdefault(tag, []).append(x)`.

Comment: `new_list` then is as easy as `list(grouped.values())`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Python, and programming in general, you should avoid creating a variable number of variables.

#### defaultdict

You can use a `defaultdict` of `list` objects. This extends naturally to an arbitrary number of groups without having to name variables explicitly.

```
first_list = [['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['a', 6], ['a', 2], ['b', 4], ['b', 5]]

from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

for cat, num in first_list:
    dd[cat].append(num)

defaultdict(list, {'a': [1, 6, 2],
                   'b': [3, 4, 5]})
```

#### groupby

The `defaultdict` solution has O(*n*) complexity, but an aptly named `itertools.groupby` solution is possible which requires sorting and O(*n* log *n*) complexity:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

sorter = sorted(first_list, key=itemgetter(0))
grouper = groupby(sorter, key=itemgetter(0))
res = {i: list(map(itemgetter(1), j)) for i, j in grouper}

{'a': [1, 6, 2], 'b': [3, 4, 5]}
```

#### List of list output

This is as trivial as calling `list` on `dict.values`:

```
res_list = list(res.values())
```

Comment: Perhaps I confused things when I said the number of values  a, b etc were unknown before runtime. In the code I am writing, I have a list of each of these values already, it is constructed by the user input at the start. I expect this should simplify things somewhat.

Comment: @Idle_92, In my opinion, this makes no difference. Even if you have 2 (or any fix number of) variables `dict` is a better idea. Programmers spend too much time writing variable names. It shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Fair enough. If I have tags = [a, b, c, d, ...] already, is it necessary to use defaultdict? Would a standard dictionary be sufficient/preferable in this case?

Comment: @Idle_92, You could pre-create your dictionary with empty lists like `d = {k: [] for k in list_of_keys}` and it would work just fine. But the whole point of `defaultdict` is this initialization is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your a and b should probably be strings.

You can do this using list comprehensions:

```
first_list = [["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["a", 6], ["a", 2], ["b", 4], ["b", 5]]
a_list = [x for x in first_list if x[0] == "a"]
b_list = [x for x in first_list if x[0] == "b"]
new_list = [a_list, b_list]
```

Comment: Doing it this way would mean looping over the first list multiple times though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to use the `itertools` library and a list-comprehension:

```
first_list = [['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['a', 6], ['a', 2], ['b', 4], ['b', 5], ...]
keyfunc = lambda x: x[0]
new_list = [[v1[1] for v1 in v] for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(first_list, key = keyfunc), key = keyfunc)]
```

What I'm doing here is grouping the list by the first value in the sublist and pulling the second value off. Note that the list needs to be sorted beforehand so this will run in `O(n log n)` time.

Answer (score 0):

A reduce would work for any numbers of tags.

```
first_list = [['a', 1], ['b', 3], ['a', 6], ['a', 2], ['b', 4], ['b', 5]]
def lambda_group(acc, val):
    tag, x = val
    if key not in acc:
        acc[key] = []
    acc[key].append(value)
    return acc
grouped_vals = reduce(lambda_group, first_list, {})
regrouped = list(grouped_vals.values())
```

Produces `[[1, 6, 2], [3, 4, 5]]`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there's a built-in methods for this in python , but in abstract algorithmic way , we could say:

```
first_list = [["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["a", 6], ["a", 2], ["b", 4], ["b", 5],["c",5]]

indx_list = [x[0] for x in first_list]

new_list = [[] for x in range(len(first_list))]

for x in first_list:
    new_list[indx_list.index(x[0])] += [x[-1]]

print(new_list)
```